# create symlinks in external drive that doesn't break when moving between computers

Tags: python, path, operating-system, symlink

When I create a symbolic link in an external drive on my mac I create a file shown below

> XSym
>
> 0077
>
> 767acf6f896cdeab83e4f3fe919d4929
>
> /Volumes/externaldrivename/path/to/audiofile/test.wav

If I move my external drive and connect to a linux machine the path of the test.wav file would be

> /media/username/externaldrivename/path/to/audiofile/test.wav

This causes the symbolic link to break.

is it possible to not have the link break by somehow setting an environment path within the xSym file so that the file path would be the same on both machines?

Specifically with a python command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets say for example that you have a file on your external volume you want to symlink to:

```
/Volumes/ExternalDrive/username/media/fileToLink.wav
```

Lets say you want to link it from here:

```
/Volumes/ExternalDrive/otherUser/folder/fileToLink.wav
```

You can issue the following commands to use a relative path. This makes the path relative to the current location but because the path is relative, the absolute file path of the drive and thus the linked files doesn't matter:

```
cd /Volumes/ExternalDrive/otherUser/folder
ln -s ../../username/media/fileToLink.wav fileToLink.wav
```

Hope this helps. I have used this technique a number of times without issues.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a symlink with relative path if that serves your purpose.